# How to do a Mail Merge

Tags: civimail

How do I start a mail merge? I would like to mail a letter to multiple contacts. Not an email, but an actual letter to receive in the mail. Can you please provide step by step instructions.

Thank you, 
Becky

Answer (score 2):

You can add tokens and produce a PDF from that as a printable item. You will find some instructions about this in the manual's [postal communication page](https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/postal-mail-communications/) (thanks to Allen for improving answer)

Comment: Pete, you beat me to the punch, but the page she will probably need is the postal communication page since it has both the pdf letter and mailing labels: https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/postal-mail-communications/

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for the quick response, both of you. I will check out that page.  Lots to learn as I am a new user.

Comment: Great. Becky you can make StackExchange 'happy' by both +1 answers but also 'accepting' answers to your own questions.